# PHP: Changing the logic of the code to switching image

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, progress-bar

I want to change the current image of the order tracking graph (or status bar it shows an img with the progress of it) I want to change the current image and change the status up to 6 (20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 90% 100%) I already made 7 image for it,

**First Code Idea**: i want, each percent "20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 90% 100%" has his own image if the status or percent is 20 it will show img 20 (the idea/code is below note: 1st code)

**2nd code bellow do:**  Right now, it takes two images, one empty and one filled, and displayed the % width of the filled one that corresponds to the % complete of a given status.
For example, for a status that is 27% complete would have 27% of the filled image displayed. If you created an empty and a filled image, and then named them the same as the default images for the plugin and uploaded them into the "images" folder of the plugin, it would use your new images instead of the default ones.

**Order tracking plugin link of this plugin**: https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-tracking/
**You can check the original code here:** Order-tracking folder > Function Folder > DisplayGraph.php

**This is the idea of my friend and i want to implement it,**

```
 <style>
        .progress{
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
        }
        .class_1{
            background-image:url(/images/image1.jpg);
        }
        .class_2{
            background-image:url(/images/image2.jpg);
        }
        .class_3{
            background-image:url(/images/image3.jpg);
        }
        .class_4{
            background-image:url(/images/image4.jpg);
        }
        .class_5{
            background-image:url(/images/image5.jpg);
        }
    </style>



    <?php
        /* define your function outside of any loops */
        function setimage( $i=0 ){
            if( $i>=0 && $i<=20 ) return 'class_1';
            elseif( $i > 20 && $i <= 40 ) return 'class_2';
            elseif( $i > 40 && $i <= 60 ) return 'class_3';
            elseif( $i > 60 && $i <= 80 ) return 'class_4';
            else return 'class_5';
        }

        /* the portion of your html that displays the graphic percentage representation */
        $ReturnString .= "<div id='progress' class='progress ".setimage( $DisplayLength )."'></div>";


    ?>
```

**And This is the code i want to change:**

```
<?php
function EWD_OTP_Display_Graph($OrderNumber) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $EWD_OTP_orders_table_name, $EWD_OTP_order_statuses_table_name;
    $Order = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $EWD_OTP_orders_table_name WHERE Order_Number='%s'", $OrderNumber));

    $Display_Graphic = get_option("EWD_OTP_Display_Graphic");
    $Statuses_Array = get_option("EWD_OTP_Statuses_Array");

    if (!is_array($Statuses_Array)) {$Statuses_Array = array();}
    foreach ($Statuses_Array as $Status_Array_Item) {if ($Status_Array_Item['Internal'] != "Yes") {$Filtered_Statuses_Array[] = $Status_Array_Item;}}
    foreach ($Filtered_Statuses_Array as $key => $Status_Array_Item) {
        if ($Order->Order_Status == $Status_Array_Item['Status']) {$CurrentStatus = $Status_Array_Item['Status']; $CurrentPercent = $Status_Array_Item['Percentage'];}
        elseif ($key == 0) {$StartingStatus = $Status_Array_Item['Status']; $StartingPercent = $Status_Array_Item['Percentage'];}
        elseif (($key+1) == sizeOf($Filtered_Statuses_Array)) {$EndingStatus = $Status_Array_Item['Status']; $EndingPercent = $Status_Array_Item['Percentage'];}
    }

    $Browser = get_user_browser();

    if ($Browser == "ie") {
            $DisplayLength = round($CurrentPercent / 100, 1) * 10;
        $ReturnString .= "<div class='ie-ewd-otp-empty-display ie-empty-graphic-" . $Display_Graphic . "'></div>";
            $ReturnString .= "<div class='ie-ewd-otp-full-display ie-full-graphic-" . $Display_Graphic . " ie-ewd-otp-display-length-" . $DisplayLength . "'></div>";
            $ReturnString .= "<div class='ie-ewd-otp-display-status' id='ie-ewd-otp-initial-status'>" . $StartingStatus . "</div>";
        $ReturnString .= "<div class='ie-ewd-otp-display-status ie-ewd-otp-current-status-length-" . $DisplayLength . "' id='ie-ewd-otp-current-status'>" . $CurrentStatus . "</div>";
        $ReturnString .= "<div class='ie-ewd-otp-display-status' id='ie-ewd-otp-ending-status'>" . $EndingStatus . "</div>";
    } else {
        if (($Display_Graphic == "Default") or ($Display_Graphic == "Streamlined") or ($Display_Graphic == "Sleek")) {  
            $DisplayLength = round($CurrentPercent / 100, 1) * 10;
            $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-empty-display'>";
            $ReturnString .= "<img src='" . EWD_OTP_CD_PLUGIN_URL . "images/" . $Display_Graphic .".png' style='width: 100%'/></div>";
            $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-full-display' style='width:" . $CurrentPercent . "%'>";
            $ReturnString .= "<img src='" . EWD_OTP_CD_PLUGIN_URL ."images/" . $Display_Graphic ."_Full.png' style='width: 100%; max-width: initial;'/></div>";
            $ReturnString .= "</div>";
            $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-statuses'>";
            $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-initial-status'>" . $StartingStatus . "</div>";
            $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status ewd-otp-current-status-length-" . $DisplayLength . "' id='ewd-otp-current-status'>" . $CurrentStatus . "</div>";
            $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-ending-status'>" . $EndingStatus . "</div>";
            $ReturnString .= "</div>";
            $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-clear'></div>";
        } else {
            if ($StartingStatus == $CurrentStatus or $EndingStatus == $CurrentStatus) {
                $ReturnString .= "<div id='ewd-otp-progressbar-" . $Display_Graphic . "'><div class='" . $Display_Graphic . "' style='width: " . $CurrentPercent . "%'></div></div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-statuses'>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-initial-status'>" . $StartingStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-ending-status'>" . $EndingStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "</div>";
            } else if ($CurrentPercent >= 75 && $EndingStatus != $CurrentStatus) {
                $ReturnString .= "<div id='ewd-otp-progressbar-" . $Display_Graphic . "'><div class='" . $Display_Graphic . "' style='width: " . $CurrentPercent . "%'></div></div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-statuses'>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-initial-status'>" . $StartingStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-current-status' style='margin-left: 55%'> " . $CurrentStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-ending-status'>" . $EndingStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "</div>";
            } else if ($CurrentPercent <= 25) {
                $ReturnString .= "<div id='ewd-otp-progressbar-" . $Display_Graphic . "'><div class='" . $Display_Graphic . "' style='width: " . $CurrentPercent . "%'></div></div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-statuses'>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-initial-status'>" . $StartingStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-current-status' style='margin-left: 5%'> " . $CurrentStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-ending-status'>" . $EndingStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "</div>";
            } else {
                $ReturnString .= "<div id='ewd-otp-progressbar-" . $Display_Graphic . "'><div class='" . $Display_Graphic . "' style='width: " . $CurrentPercent . "%'></div></div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-statuses'>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-initial-status'>" . $StartingStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-current-status' style='margin-left: " . ($CurrentPercent-20) . "%'> " . $CurrentStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "<div class='ewd-otp-display-status' id='ewd-otp-ending-status'>" . $EndingStatus . "</div>";
                $ReturnString .= "</div>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $ReturnString;
}
function get_user_browser() {
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ub = '';
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $ub = "ie";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $ub = "firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $ub = "safari";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $ub = "chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Flock/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $ub = "flock";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $ub = "opera";
    }
    return $ub;
}
?>
```

**Thank You!**

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose a totally different approach: **to create bargraphs ad hoc**.

From the point of view of the HTML code, bargraphs are images that are included when a web page is displayed or updated. But, these images are not static image files in this case; they are created dynamically by a php script instead.

Advantages:

- Seamless scale, real values, not only steps
- Enhanced functionality, e.g. colors, limits, grid.

Disadvantages:

- Request to be send to the server for every update.
- Graph images can not be pre-loaded, are transferred each time.

The code shown below has been created to display graphs of resources, but can be equally used to create progress graphs. The graphs simply are bar graphs. There are a couple of parameters available to taylor the graphs.

### Parameters

- width: width of the graph (pixels)
- height: height of the graph (pixels)
- value: progress value (percents)
- limit1: 1st warning limit (100-value*, percents)
- limit2: 2nd warning limit(100-value*, percents)
- grid: whether to show a grid ('true') or not ('false', or parameter not set)
- color: color name, (one of 'white', 'black', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey', 'midgrey', 'grey', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'blue', 'darkblue', 'green', 'red', 'lightred')
- rgb: color value in RGB notation; overwrites 'color' parameter.
  Red, green, and blue values can be either written as decimal values (e.g. 255) or as hexadecimal values (e.g. 0xFF).
  Red, green, and blue values are separated by pipe characters (|).
  Example: rgb=255|0x33|0x70

(*) When a resource has been consumed up to the corresponding amount.

### Usage example

You can generate the `<img .../>` tags thru a php script on the server side. You also can set the 'src' attribute of an 'img' element by a piece of Javascript on the client side.

Example HTML code:

```
<img id="progressbar" src="/bargraph.php?width=180&height=12&value=33&color=blue&grid=false" alt="Progress" />
```

Example Javascript code:

```
var progress = 0;

function setProgressBar(id,progress) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  if (var) var.src = "/bargraph.php?width=180&height=12&value=" + progress + "&color=blue&grid=true";
}

// Maybe periodically do ...
progress += 5;
setProgressBar("progressbar", progress);
// ...
```

How it would look like (with grid):

[image]

### Code (bargraph.php)

```
<?php
// We honor both request methods (GET/POST)
$params = array();
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) $params[strtolower($key)] = $value;

// Assume default values if necessary
$wd = (empty($params{'width'})) ? 40 : (integer)$params{'width'};
$hg = (empty($params{'height'})) ? 8 : (integer)$params{'height'};
$vl = (empty($params{'value'})) ? 0 : (integer)$params{'value'};
$l1 = (empty($params{'limit1'})) ? 0 : 100-(integer)$params{'limit1'};
$l2 = (empty($params{'limit2'})) ? 0 : 100-(integer)$params{'limit2'};
$gr = (empty($params{'grid'})) ? 0 : ( (strtolower($params{'grid'})=='true') ? 1 : 0) ;

// Set grid parameters
define('numgrid',10);
if ($gr) {
    $xd = floor($wd / numgrid); $wd = $xd * numgrid;
    $wd0 = $wd;
    $wd -= 1;
} else {
    $xd = 0;
    $wd0 = $wd;
}

// Create the image
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($wd,$hg);

// Define color palette
$colors = array(
    'white' => imagecolorallocate($img,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF),
    'black' => imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0),
    'lightgrey' => imagecolorallocate($img,0xE0,0xE0,0xE0),
    'darkgrey' => imagecolorallocate($img,0x66,0x66,0x66),
    'midgrey' => imagecolorallocate($img,0x99,0x99,0x99),
    'grey' => imagecolorallocate($img,0xC0,0xC0,0xC0),
    'yellow' => imagecolorallocate($img,0xFF,0xFF,0x00),
    'orange' => imagecolorallocate($img,0xFF,0xD7,0x00),
    'brown' => imagecolorallocate($img,0x66,0x66,0x00),
    'cyan' => imagecolorallocate($img,0x00,0xc0,0xc0),
    'magenta' => imagecolorallocate($img,0xc0,0x00,0x90),
    'blue' => imagecolorallocate($img,0x00,0x00,0xc0),
    'darkblue' => imagecolorallocate($img,0x00,0x51,0x8C),
    'green' => imagecolorallocate($img,0x00,0xc0, 0x00),
    'red' => imagecolorallocate($img,0xCC,0x00, 0x00),
    'lightred' => imagecolorallocate($img,0xFF,0x33, 0x33),
);
if (isset($params['rgb']) && !empty($params['rgb'])) {
    $col = explode('|',$params['rgb']);
    if (count($col)==3) {
        $colors['rgb'] = imagecolorallocate($img,$col[0],$col[1],$col[2]);
        $params['color']='rgb';
    }
}

// Evaluate colors 
$params['color']= strtolower($params['color']);
$lim1_color = $colors['yellow'];
$lim2_color = $colors['lightred'];
$color = (isset($params['color']) && isset($colors[$params['color']]))  
    ? $params['color']
    : 'cyan';
$active_color = $colors[$color];
if ($gr) {
    $inactive_color = $colors['grey'];
    $background_color = ($color=='midgreay') 
        ? $colors['lightgreay'] 
        : $colors['midgrey'];
    $delim_color = $colors['white'];
} else {
    $inactive_color =  $colors['white'];
    $background_color = $colors['grey'];
}


// Fill image with active / inactive colors
$x1 = 0; $y1 = 0;
if (($wd>3) && ($hg>3)) {
    imagefill($img,0,0,$background_color);
    imagefilledrectangle ($img,$x1+1,$y1+1,$wd0-2,$hg-2,$inactive_color);
} else {
    imagefill($img,0,0,$inactive_color);
}
$x2 = ceil(($wd0 / 100) * $vl);
if ($x2>0) { imagefilledrectangle ($img,$x1,$y1,$x2-1,$hg-1,$active_color); }
// Paint grid and limit bars
if ($gr) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= (numgrid); $i++) {
        $x1 = ($i * $xd);
            imageline($img,$x1,0,$x1,$hg-1,$delim_color);
    }
}
if ($l1) { $x2 = ceil(($wd0 / 100) * $l1); imageline($img,$x2,0,$x2,$hg-1,$lim1_color); }
if ($l2) { $x2 = ceil(($wd0 / 100) * $l2); imageline($img,$x2,0,$x2,$hg-1,$lim2_color); }

// Avoid caching
header("Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1999 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); // Always modified
header("Cache-Control: private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0

// Send out, then destroy the image
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Of course you could modify the code to change the way a bar graph finally looks.